# Resign first responder doesn't work when picker is show

Tags: ios

I've a problem with date picker. When I touch on textfield(datumletu) I call picker and datumletu [resign firstresponder]. But no effect. 
Here is my code. I'm trying everything but nothing is working.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {    
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

if (textField == self.datumLetu) {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
  [self.autoTextFieldPriletu resignFirstResponder];
  [self.autoTextField resignFirstResponder];
  [self.cisloLetu resignFirstResponder];

    [self.datumLetu resignFirstResponder];
    self.picker.hidden = YES;
    [self showPicker];

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

    if(rect.origin.y == 0)
    {
        rect.origin.y -= 110;
        rect.size.height += 110;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            self.view.frame = rect;
        }];
        self.picker.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight / 2 +  screenHeight / 3.2, screenWidth, screenHeight/2);

    }
```

and picker

```
-(void)showPicker
{
    [self showAction];
}
 -(void) showAction
 {
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    self.picker = [[Picker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenHeight / 2 +  screenHeight / 10.5, screenWidth, screenHeight/2)];
[self.picker addTargetForDoneButton:self action:@selector(cancelPressed)];
[self.picker addTargetForCancelButton:self action:@selector(cancelPressed)];

[self.picker setMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime];
[self.picker.picker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:self.picker];
self.picker.hidden = NO;

}
```

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar problem, abut not sure if it's of interest. Probably way too late for you in any event. The problem I had was: I presented the picker, and during the process of presenting the picker, I tried to resign the first responder. That didn't work. I found I had to resign the first responder *before* starting the process of presenting the picker.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ViewController` add the delegate of the `UITextField` :

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

While Creating the `UITextField` or in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
self.myTextField.delegate = self;
```

In your implementation file:

```
 #pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

   // show your picker here 

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return NO; 
}
```